# how to see my SD-card peripherials?

Tags: sd-card, devuan

I want to know the hardware that reads SD Cards.

I don't have `lspci`, `lsusb`, nor internet access to download packages.

**System**

```
# uname -a  
Linux devuan-droid4 5.4.0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Jan 12 19:38:25 UTC 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

**Attempts**

```
# dmidecode    
# dmidecode 3.0
Scanning /dev/mem/ for entry point.
Bus error
```

---

e.g. in Debian I would do

```
# lspci | grep -a "SD"    
03:00.0 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller (rev 07)
```

and conclude I am using [Ricoh Co Ltd PCIe SDXC/MMC Host Controller](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Ricoh%20Co%20Ltd%20PCIe%20SDXC%2FMMC&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images)

Comment: Did you tried `dmesg` ?

Comment: that's a good hint, but the output is very long... and the debian system returns nothing for `dmesg | grep -a "Ricoh"`

Comment: Have a look at the `/sys/` directory tree, in particular `/sys/bus`. You didn't tell as **anything** about your hardware, but "droid" and "arm7l" make it likely you don't have PCI devices in the first place. So look for whatever you *do* have. I can't narrow it down further.

Comment: @dirkt: thank you for the hints! indeed there is no PCI. it is a Smartphone motherboard. The hardware looks like this: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Motorola+Droid+4+Teardown/7759 I wish to get information about it from the command line

Comment: So go through `dmesg`, go through `/sys`, see what you have. Even if it's long. No, `grep` won't help. If you have a working SD card you can see with `mount`, you may able to work backwards from the filesystem through `/sys`. And we cannot do this remotely for you, without being able to investigate all those things.